# App not showing in open with in email client in iOS13 for pdf file

Tags: pdf, ios13

This was working properly in iOS12 but does not work in 13.1.2

Other extensions that are not public files work just fine.

I have tried changing the extension to “anyuniqueextension” and that doesn’t work.  If I use the same info list code but change the extension to pdfx that will work.

Not sure of what to try next.

Comment: Just updated to 13.1.3 no change, still can’t copy pdf files to my app